# Pandas - Deleting a row with a certain word

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and python and I thought I wouldn't need to post but I'm in the situation where I have to. I have rows which have some values as blanked, however these rows have values with no location in it for a column. I was wondering how do I drop the row with a value of 'No Location' in it?

I did try dropNa but it didn't work, and I know drop() is a function but I'm just unsure how would I apply it to this. The 'No Location' value is part of the 'Location' column as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe (and the code to instantiate it) and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "~" to drop the values you don't need.

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 2, 6]})
drop_value = [1, 2]
df = df[~df['A'].isin(drop_value)]

   A  B
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you need is just to remove rows where a certain column(say your column is 'A') has a value of 'No Location' in it but retaining rows where Location column has this value,

```
df = df[df.A != 'No Location']
```

will remove the rows where your A column has the value 'No location'

Comment: Tried but it still didn't remove it, my code is this:     df = df[df.Location != 'No Location']

Comment: do you need to remove rows where column Location has the value 'No location'?